# Call C# function to get string In C

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I am trying to call C# function to get string result, But it doesn't work.
How to get string from C# to C with C function.
Somebody help?

C#

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void GetStrCallback(StringBuilder str);


[DllImport("...")]
public extern static void SetStrCallback(GetStrCallback cb);

...

public static void Handle(StringBuilder str)
{
   str.Append("AAAAAA");
}


SetStrCallback(Handle);
```

C

```
typedef void(__stdcall * GetStrCallback)(const char* str);
GetStrCallback _getStrFunc = NULL;

extern __declspec(dllexport) void SetStrCallback(GetStrCallback cb)
{
    _getStrFunc = cb;
}

...

void GetCSharpStr()
{
    char temStr[1024] = "";
    _getStrFunc(temStr);     // Call C# function to get result, But temStr is empty. How to get it???

}
```

Comment: This isn't the issue you're having right now (but it will bite you): you need to save the `GetStrCallback` delegate you create which points to `Handle` somewhere. Otherwise the GC will collect it, and then calling `_getStrFunc` will fail. It's usual to store it in a field.

Comment: How doesnt it work?

Comment: `GetStrCallback` on C# side is declared to accept a reference to StringBuilder while you can only pass pointer on C side.

Comment: `delegate void GetStrCallback(ref StringBuilder str);` if i add `ref`, Program will crash.

Comment: having `StringBuilder` in the marshalling to C looks strange since this is managed class that would not work in unmanaged code. Could you please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings) and use something like `void PassStringRef2([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string s);`?

Comment: @oleksa using a `StringBuilder` in p/invoke is perfectly normal. The marshaller knows how to use it. It's used for strings which can be changed by native code, since `string` is immutable

Comment: This can't work. You are expecting the C# marshaller to create a `StringBuilder` object. It would need to know how large the unmanaged array was in order to marshal the data in both directions. It just isn't going to do that for you. When you use  `StringBuilder` in the traditional manner (C# calling into unmanaged) then the marshaler has that information. Not going to work for reverse p/invoke. You may have to marshal manually. Alternatively you could arrange for the C# code to return a COM BSTR. But I'm not sure that will work with reverse p/invoke.

Comment: A big flaw in your current API design is that, even if it worked, you have no defence against buffer overrun. This is why any API that asks the callee to populate an array passes both the array and its size / length. You must get into the habit of doing that. If you do end up marshaling manually, you'll need to provide size / length.

Comment: And as a minor aside, `const char* str` isn't correct when you expect the callee to modify the array.